# Python how to change ' from the string type

Tags: python, list

i have a list in python that looks like this `['a','b','c']` and i want it to look like `["a","b","c"]`. I tried using some replace functions and looping the list and adding `'"'` before and after the element but its not working.
I receive the list from the import block in terraform as dictionary and also the replace function is not working there. I need it to look like this `["a","b","c"]` because i want to generate another terraform file that will use that list for a variable but using `'` in terraform for strings is not working.
How can i solve this?

Comment: The quotes aren't actually part of the python string. You need to write a custom function to output formatted strings the way you want. Something like `'{ "{0}": "whatever", "{1}": "something else", "{2}": "you get the idea" }'.format(your_list)`. Make a multiline template string with your terraform and format it with your data.

Comment: Trying to read through the lines: you might be looking for json.dumps()

Comment: @Guillaume terraform uses HCL, not JSON. They'll need to make a custom template string.

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710954/putting-double-quotes-for-an-output-string) or probably a whole bunch of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to dump a list in json format.
Python has a [module in its standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for it.

```
import json

l = ['a', 'b']
print(l)
l_str = json.dumps(l)
print(l_str)
```

Comment: Terraform uses HCL, not JSON.

Comment: @JaredSmith i got the desired output in the terraform file

Comment: @JaredSmith, from the HCL docs: "[...] However, HCL does have a JSON-based alternative syntax, which allows the same structure above to be generated using a standard JSON serializer when users wish to generate configuration programmatically rather than hand-write it"